# Access IP-camera with matlab

Tags: matlab, axis, ip-camera

I want to connect the IP-Cam (Axis P3905-R) to Matlab with the following script:

```
function readIPVideo()
cam = ipcam('http://192.168.13.125/mjpg/video.mjpg');%no login and password necessary
preview(cam);
closePreview(cam);
clear cam;
end
```

I get the following error-message:

```
"Error using readIPVideo (line 6)
Cannot connect to the IP Camera Stream URL. Make sure the URL is correct and authentication is provided if needed."
```

If I put the URL into a browser, there is a connection to IP-Cam as well as in VLC-Player. Why it doesn't work with Matlab? I'm using Matlab R2015a. The error occurs in Suse Linux Leap as well as in Windows 10.

Thanks for help,
Miriam