# Connect matlab to ip camera

Tags: matlab, image-processing, vlc, ip-camera, obs

Similar problem like [Access IP-camera with matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673327/access-ip-camera-with-matlab)

I tried to read in two different IP Cams (Ubiquiti UniFi UVC G3 and a virtual camera via OBS Studio) independently.

It works with the VLC player, but not with Matlab.
Unfortunately the [matlab help](https://de.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/ipcamera/ug/find-ip-camera-url.html) could not help me either.
I get the error: Cannot connect to the IP Camera Stream URL. Make sure the URL is correct and authentication is provided if
needed.

I entered the URL from the interface (stand alone mode) of the camera or from the OBS-Studio into VLC and in VLC the video is displayed. I also checked the codec information from the VLC. Compared to the matlab help I have 2 streams, but the video stream is H264 [(see picture1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8sJI.png) [(see picture2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BpKW.png).

Code for connecting to virtual camera:

```
cam=ipcam('rtsp://localhost:554/live')
```

Code for connecting to UniFi camera:

```
cam=ipcam('rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/s0','user','pw'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!